# Configure clojure syntax highlighting for gedit

Tags: ubuntu, clojure, syntax-highlighting, gedit

How can gedit be configured to highlight Clojure source files?

By default it treats `.clj` files as plain text.

Comment: Why Gedit? Don’t you think there are better editors for Clojure around? I’m not saying Emacs at once, but even Sublime seems to be better prepared, and have more interesting plugins to work with Lisps at all.

Answer (score 1):

This [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mitko/clojure_for_gedit) contains some files you'll need for this task.

However the `install.sh` script doesn't quite work correctly.

After cloning, use the following:

```
if [ -d "/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0" ]
then
  sudo cp clojure.lang /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/clojure.lang
fi

if [ -d "/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0" ]
then
  sudo cp clojure.lang /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/clojure.lang
fi

sudo cp clojure.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/clojure.xml
cd /usr/share/
sudo update-mime-database mime
```

Answer (score 0):

The Github repo you've linked to is quite nice, however, I've found that there are several problems with it.  Here are some of them:

- doesn't recognize all symbol characters, e.g. `log-2`
- doesn't recognize `#!` comments
- doesn't recognize long escapes in strings

I've attempted to address these and other issues in [my own repo](https://github.com/mattfenwick/gedit-clojure):

[image]